# Маленькая звёздочка доброты на фоне всепоглощающей чёрной дыры

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, предложение

### Не пора ли стать добрее и дружелюбнее?

Для начала немного предыстории...
Меня уже сложно назвать молодым человеком. 
Мир непрестанно меняется. И на ярком фоне этих перемен, учитывая пережитые годы перестройки и неумолимых 90-х, когда каждый боролся за свою жизнь и жизнь своих родных и близких, многие из нас, а так же соответственно и многие родители нынешнего поколения, в подавляющем своём большинстве, прививали своим детям необходимость заботы в первую очередь о себе. 
Делалось это не из стремления сделать новое поколение озлобленней, а из лучших побуждений. Каждый родитель больше своей жизни переживает за жизнь и успех своих детей. Конечно же я не говорю про всех, но будем откровенны - от народа, родившихся в СССР нередко можно услышать фразы типа "Надо идти по головам", "Не позаботишься ты о себе - этого никто не сделает", "Не обманешь-не проживёшь"(Фраза намеренно была адаптированна с разговорного). Не будем разбирать сейчас то множество причин, которые побудили людей кардинально изменить мировоззрение людей.

Мне посчастливилось активно присоединиться к данному сообществу с 19 декабря 2019г. Как ребёнок, каждый день с улыбкой до ушей я заходил в данное сообщество с искреннем желанием помочь... В наше время не так много можно было найти информации для обучения программированию, и приходилось с большинством задач справляться самостоятельно. Каждый, из тех, кто постарше прекрасно знает то чувство, когда очень долго не получается решить ту или иную задачу, раскаляя нервы до предела. И они не по наслышке знают, какие позитивные чувства вызывает та помощь, которая может быть получена из любых источников.

### `Stackoverflow` и `habr` вывели эту помощь на новый, недоступный ранее уровень.

Но, если **habr** отдал предпочтение тому виду информации в виде статей, которую ранее могли получать люди занимающиеся программирования, только из журналов типа *CHIP* Byte Россия* *PC magazine* *Xakep* и так далее, то **stackoverflow** выбрал иной стиль новой чистой, искренней и безвозмездной помощи, за что ему огромное спасибо.

**Основной наградой в данном сообществе является возможность помогать.**
И я хотел бы акцентировать на этом внимание. Не зарабатывать рейтинг, не искать возможность получения подработки через данное сообщество, выполняя задачи на заказ, и не желание казаться умнее других. 
Тем не менее и данном сообществе есть очень много агрессивных людей, стремящихся вылить свой негатив, накопившийся внутри, на других.

Несколько дней нахожусь в неприятном диссонансе желания покинуть сообщество.

Кто-то старается не обращать на это внимание, кто-то просто игнорирует, как, например, часть модераторов. А ведь сколько было здесь на мете громких заявлений тех самых кандидатов в модераторы. Впрочем, не нам ли знать, что выполнять обещания в нашей стране - это уже моветон.

Я призываю каждого члена данного, уникального сообщества быть добрее. К чему высказывать своё негодование? Сама система `stackoverflow` смоделирована таким образом, чтобы каждый мог дополнить ответ друг друга( а не писать раз за разом язвительные комментарии), чтобы каждый мог без ощущения стыда задать свой вопрос(А не получать на него сходу гневные комментарии, особенно с обращением на "ты"). 
Меня тоже сложно назвать примером для подражания. Я нетерпим к тем, кто ставит задачи, вместо того, чтобы задавать вопрос, хотя это тоже не повод быть столь резким, как я бываю. 
Суть заключается в том, что необходимо соблюдать рамки приличия не только тем, кто отвечает на вопросы, но и тем, кто их задаёт. 
Не надо писать, что это только имеет место быть только в локальном формате, ведь далеко не я один это замечаю.

### Но вместе мы можем сделать всё сообщество добрее и продуктивнее

Не надо писать гневные комментарии, лучше дополните ответ своими знаниями, или, если он сильно отличается от Вашего мнения, лучше добавьте свой ответ.
Не стоит писать комментарии авторам из разряда "Да кто так вообще код пишет" или "А ничего, что у Вас там 100 запросов, тут двадцать вызовов функции". Неужели так сложно вместо этого в нормальном формате объяснить человеку, как лучше ему адаптировать код, и какие преимущества это может принести? Будьте уверены, что подобные ответы оценят гораздо большее количество людей, чем злые комментарии.
Откуда такая ненависть к коллегам? Лишь единицы имеют мужество написать добрые комментарии, но абсолютно каждый готов высказать своё "фи", причём зачастую в совершенно не приемлемом формате. Видимо это просто такая идеология людей.

Не пора ли сделать это сообщество чуть добрее? И Вам самим будет приятнее раз за разом посещать данное сообщество, и это сможет помочь привлечь гораздо больше людей, расширив рамки содружества программистов.

Я отдаю себе отчёт в том, что данное сообщение, скорее всего, вызовет наибольшее количество негативных сообщений о тех, кто не может жить без негатива, чем по-настоящему сможет побудить каждого искренне задуматься над этим в своём собственном уникальном внутреннем мире.

Тем не менее за эти 2 месяца мне посчастливилось познакомиться со многими уникальными людьми, которыми я искренне восхищаюсь. И я безгранично благодарен им за их ответы, которые, даже спустя время могут научить других новым подходам и видению решения задач.

Спасибо Вам ребята. Мне было очень приятно быть с Вами в "одной лодке". 
Всем доброго дня и частичку доброты Вам в душу.

Обнял - подкинул ((с.) одного из авторов вопроса)

Comment: Хотел бы отметить, что в нашем сообществе далеко не у всех хорошо развиты так называемые софт-скиллы и все-таки стоит предполагать добрые намерения, а очевидные негатив и оскорбления - просто флагать

Comment: Мелкое замечание по содержанию - _выполнять обещания в нашей стране - это уже моветон._ В какой стране? Сообщество - SO на русском языке, а не для россиян.

Comment: Видеть грубость в обращении на ты в интернете - это моветон.

Comment: @yolosora главное не флаги, главное - не уподобляться. Периодически приходят флаги от участников об оскорблении, но при этом эти же участники сами вступают в подобные перепалки. Довольно лицемерно выглядит порой (:

Comment: Никаких проблем в обращении на "ты" не вижу. Я не знаю возраста чувака, его положения и всего такого. Для меня это такой же собеседник, как я сам. В тыщщу раз проще общаться на "ты" без этих псевдоуважительных выканий. Не сэры собрались. Кодер с кодером перетирают ))

Comment: Именно. *Я не знаю возраста чувака, его положения и всего такого. Для меня это такой же собеседник, как я сам.* И поэтому я предпочитаю относиться к нему с уважением, и на "вы". И не использовать сленг, который может быть непонятен собеседнику.

Comment: @yolosora Извините, а что такое **софт-скиллы** ?? Я могу предположить **софт- это софа**, **скилл - это киль**, из этого следует фраза "лежать на киле" либо "направлять путь к софе" , верно ли я размышляю ??

Comment: Я понимаю проблему, но не понимаю, что конкретно автор предлагает? Я не вижу рычагов, как уменьшить количество хамства или хамов на ресурсе. Мало того, в некоторых случаях само по себе хамство может быть вещью чисто субъективной. У меня даже были случаи, когда мои сообщения флагали и меня называли «токсичным», но я, например, себя таким не считаю.

Comment: @timob256 [Гибкие навыки](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Comment: @tym32167 а зачем тогда использовать американские смысловые конструкции  когда есть русские-евразийские смысловые конструкции  **0_о** ??

Comment: @timob256 потому что это разрешено законом и является общеупотребительным термином. Я уже понял, что ваш вопрос с подвохом, но он никак не относится к вопросу автора и ему не место в комментариях под этим вопросом.

Comment: @tym32167 увы, если я с вами соглашусь то мы оба были бы не правы :3

Comment: Еще, кстати, почему то уже не в первый раз поднимается тема хамства, но примеры все про то, как отвечающий хамит вопрошающему. Все эти «будьте дружелюбны» и «новый участник» явно говорят нам, что мы (кто уже на сайте) должны заботиться о вновь прибывших или о тех, кто задает вопросы. Но что насчет обратной стороны? Например, когда вижу вопрос-задание или вопрос-писульку без каких либо подробностей или вопрос-просто какой то кусок кода, то я это воспринимаю как хамство всему сообществу. Как с этим предлагается бороться? Предполагаю, что никак, т.к. любые требования к новичкам понизят kpi

Comment: @Suvitruf says Reinstate Monica Вступать в полемику с кем-либо не является лицемерием. И уж тем более, если в данных сообщениях не было оскорблений. То, как Вы можете воспринимать происходящее - зависит лишь от Вашего личного мировоззрения. И крайне жаль, что именно модераторы интерпретируют их не корректно. А вот кардинальные различия сообщений в предвыборной компании и на деле, на мой взгляд, и является истинным лицемерием.

Comment: @tym32167 Я с Вами согласен, и упоминал об этом в посте. Суть заключается в том, что необходимо соблюдать рамки приличия не только тем, кто отвечает на вопросы, но и тем, кто их задаёт.

Comment: Вы же сами понимаете, что это недостижимый идеал? К тому же у каждого свои рамки приличия. Это никак не побороть.

Comment: @tym32167 Да, я это осознаю. Но к этому можно стремиться, а не воспринимать это как устоявшееся данное. Данный пост был нацелен не на публичное "группирование" по хорошим и плохим, а как попытка пробудить внутренние размышления в каждом человеке. Ведь истинной причины для агрессии просто нет. Вопросы можно менять, ответы можно дополнять или корректировать и так далее. И это, по-настоящему приятно - делать доброе дело. Не так ли?

Comment: Я рассматриваю ваш пост просто как крик души. 99% хамов его не увидят, из оставшегося процента я не уверен, что кто то сделает какие то выводы. За попытку плюс конечно, но я не вижу как это повлияет на что либо. Вы еще в драмах не участвовали, вот это неплохой опыт, вот где реальная проверка ожиданий реальностью, чтобы осознать кто мы есть на сайте и что мы тут делаем и зачем.

Comment: @tym32167 Это и есть отчасти крик души. Очередная попытка пробудить собственное сознание в ходе размышлений, а не следование общественному мнению. Мне нравится сама идея и смысл данного сообщества, чего не скажешь о том подходе, который используют люди. Изменить всё можно лишь поняв, что ни один язвительный комментарий не несёт под собой никакой пользы. Ни информационной, ни моральной.

Comment: хех, взяли и закрыли как дубликат. И-ирония

Comment: @Denis640Kb оффтопик, но тут нет лс, увидел это и вспомнил Вас : https://twitter.com/AlanZucconi/status/1315967202797981696

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Приветствую ))) Рад снова Вас видеть. С огромным удовольствием почитал )